# How to use preposition of software?

Tags: grammar

I often use "I write code on my computer." is it correct?

And...

The question is

"I do my report on/in Word.", "I do xxx on/in Excel."

How to use the preposition with the software/applications?

Comment: "I do my report on Word" means: I write a report, and the subject of the report is Word.

Answer (score 1):

Though it’s not a preposition, I usually use “using,” e.g., “I’m writing my code for the assignment using Python3.”

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, since it raises the issue of how we describe our interactions with computers and computer programs.

At the moment, and to answer your question directly, *in Word* and *in Excel* would be the conventional forms.

However, one can also imagine dictating a report to a digital assistant such as Siri or Alexa, which frequently have female names, and which some people think of as intelligent entities in their own right.

Writing *in Alexa* or *on Alexa* does not sound quite appropriate. On the other hand, writing *with Alexa* suggests a kind of creative partnership, which also doesn’t sound right, although I suspect that over time it might.

This to say that although the question of *in* or *on* is on the surface grammatical, it can actually tell us more.